# How to set the AssemblyName using CodeDom?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, codedom

I am createing an EXE on the fly from my own code using codedom.

I can set all the attributes like Title, Description, Company... but I can't set the **AssemblyName**. Any ideas how to do it? Here is the code part I add on top before a Class:

```
Imports System.Reflection
'This works but the AssemblyName is set to the name of the exe file:
'If I rename the exe the assembly name also changes.
<Assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitle("Title123"> )
<Assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyDescription("Description123">)
<Assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompany("qxxx enterprises">)


'I tried to add the following but it throws me an error
'"AssemblyName" cannot be used as an attribute because it does not inherit from 'System.Attribute'
<Assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyName("Testapp123"> )
```

Any ideas how to set the AssemblyName? (I am not asking to change it after the exe was compiled.)

Comment: AssemblyName is not an attribute.  It is what you automatically get *after* compiling from CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly.FullName.  Sounds like you actually want to change the display name, use the CompilerParameters.OutputAssembly property for that.